# JHipster social login with Android

Tags: jhipster

The JHipster is running fine and added login via Facebook and also is running fine on the web.
My problem is that I have an Android application that already performs the sign in JHipster, but now I'm a little confused as to how I integrate Android authentication with Facebook. Basically I did not understand what endpoint it should call on JHipster after Facebook token return.
I imagine you're not prepared to be used with Android as the "social/sigin" uses browser session data.

Someone has gone through it and help me?
I will continue and remake the "social/signin" to not use the WebRequest but I'm not sure if this is the best way.